# What's the difference between these ls command line arguments: -d vs *

Tags: linux, ls

What's the difference between

```
ls /example or ls /example/
```

vs

```
ls -d /example/*
```

Why do they give (almost) the same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you're giving *ls* a directory and asking to show its contents.

In the second case, you're already giving *ls* the contents directly (a list of individual files & subdirectories), and asking to show exactly those items but *not* their further contents.

So these give the same output because they *do* nearly the same thing, except in the former case *ls* itself determines what contents it needs to show, while in the latter case you're giving it a pre-determined list.

---

*Ls* has two modes: when given a file, it shows just that file; when given a directory, it shows the *contents* of that directory (one level deep).

Your `/example` is a directory, so when you use `ls /example`, *ls* will show its contents. The `-d` option disables this behavior and makes *ls* **always** show just the item given, whether it's a file or not.

(Compare: `ls -l /etc` and `ls -l -d /etc`)

But when you use `ls -d /example/*`, you're not asking it to show a directory – you're giving it **a list of individual items** to show. The wildcards are expanded by your shell before the command gets run, so what you're really running is `ls -d /example/file1 /example/file2 /example/file3`.

Answer (score 1):

When an argument to `ls` is a directory, `ls` enters the directory and lists the directory contents, unless it was called with `-d`. And remember that the filename expansion ('file*') is done in the shell before calling ls, so it you have:

```
dir
├── file1
└── subdir
    └── file2
```

- `ls dir` lists the contents of `dir` (one line for `file1`, one for `subdir`)
- `ls -d dir` only lists `dir` (on a single line)
- `ls dir/*` is expanded to `ls dir/file1 dir/subdir` and so expands `subdir` to list its contents
- `ls -d dir/*` is expanded to `ls dir/file1 dir/subdir`, but due to the `-d` `subdir` is not expanded and only `file1` and `subdir` are listed (so you get the same output as in the first case).